# Actively searching for a username in meteor ionic with angular

Tags: search, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor, meteoric

I'm trying to get meteor to search for a username as the user types. For example typing in "a" would give users "admin", "adam" and "apple". "ad" would give "admin", "adam" etc..

In the controller I have:

```
this.helpers({
  users() {
    return Meteor.users.find({username:this.searchText});
  }
});
```

and in the template I have

```html
<ion-content>
<div class="new-chat.search">
  <label class="item item-input">
        <input ng-model="searchText" type="search" placeholder="Enter a username">
      </label>
 </div>
    <div class="list">
      <a ng-repeat="user in chat.users" ng-click="chat.newChat(user._id)" class="item">
        <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
  <h3>{{ user.profile.name }}</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

If "this.searchText" is chaneged to 'admin' it will return admin.

Anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for a partial match I guess.  You could use a regular expression for that. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

For example:

```
return Meteor.users.find({username: $regex: {this.searchText, $options: 'i'}});
```